# Background-image does not display

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a background image using CSS, but the image does not display. I am doing the exact same thing as the [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp), but it does not work.

How do I show a background image for the entire page?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/pozRMXm)

```css
div {
      background-image: url('https://imgur.com/a/Fql6rTU');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your url is incorrect, this is not image format. Try with this one: https://i.imgur.com/kkQFh8p.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.When you are displaying an image in a division use `background-size: cover` so thaat image covers the division fully and then try to mention the `height` and `width` of the division.

2.You have given the wrong URL for the image and correct it and it will work.
Hope this is what you are looking for

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kkQFh8p.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an IMGUR page URL instead of actual image URL - open the page, right-click the image, and pick "copy image link" (also shown separately after uploading)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/kkQFh8p.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

background-image url parameter need to be with image format extension, you need to change it on 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejeSN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to put there height with for that div which is with background image

```css
div{
background:#006;padding:50px 0; background:url(https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/travel/rights-exempt/2018-travel-photographer-of-the-year/magical-mountains/dawn-vestrahorn-iceland-mountains.jpg); background-size:cover;
width:100%;
height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hope so this will help you Thanks.